# "A healthy food" or "healthy food"

Tags: countability

Is *a* required before *healthy food* in my sentence?

> I like fast food, but it's not a healthy food.

Comment: Not even the second *food* is required, just "I like fast food, but it's not healthy." Anyway, its not the food that is healthy or unhealthy – that's you, or the act of eating it.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Fast food is unhealthy" is natural (at least here in Canada), and is understood to mean "eating fast food is unhealthy".

Comment: Yes.  Everyone in the US refers directly to food and other things like exercise as healthy.  It obviously means good for your health.  My mind was about to be blown by @WeatherVane's suggestion that it doesn't mean that in the UK, but the UK dictionaries online have that definition too.

Comment: @cruthers where? Lexico does not mention food under [**healthy**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/healthy) nor mention health under [**fast food**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fast_food). Just because you understand what people mean does not make it good English.

Comment: @WeatherVane: take a look at 1.2 in Lexico - "indicating or promoting good health" - that's what healthy food does.  Pull down the list of examples.  Also look at Cambridge def A2: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/healthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the following are likely to be used by fluent speaker, and would be easily understood by most speakers:

> - I like fast food, but it's not a healthy food.
> - I like fast food, but it's not healthy food.
> - I like fast food, but it's not healthy.
> - I like fast food, but it's unhealthy.

There is perhaps a slight difference of nuance, but I would hate to try to define it. For practical purposes the meanings of all four are essentially identical.

I think one can speak of "a healthy food", "a healthy dish" or "healthy food" just as one might speak of "a tasty dish".  Being "healthy" is an attribute of the food. Obviously it means food which supports or enhances the health of a typical person.